# Facing this issue while loading data from oracle to snowflake using s3

Tags: oracle, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

-Data from oracle is downloaded using python script and saved as'.csv' in s3 and it is uploaded into in snowflake tables from staged location.
-It's working fine when column data type is changed to varchar, when i change the column back to Numeric this error is popping.
-used the custom file format.

ERROR: Numeric value ' ' is not recognized File 'xxxxx', line 2, character 291 Row 1, column "mytable"["COL":130]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT CSV_SKIP_PIPE_HEADER
                      TYPE = CSV 
                      RECORD_DELIMITER ='\n',
                      FIELD_DELIMITER ='|',
                      FILE_EXTENSION =null,
                      SKIP_HEADER=1,
                      DATE_FORMAT=AUTO,
                      TIME_FORMAT=AUTO,
                      TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=AUTO,
                      BINARY_FORMAT=HEX,
                      ESCAPE=NONE,
                      ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD='\\',
                      TRIM_SPACE=true,
                      FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='\"',
                      NULL_IF=(''),
                      COMPRESSION=AUTO,
                      ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH=TRUE,
                      VALIDATE_UTF8=TRUE,
                      SKIP_BLANK_LINES=FALSE,
                      REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS=TRUE,
                      EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL=TRUE,
                      SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK=TRUE,
                      ENCODING=UTF8
 ;
```

- using this command to copy data into table

```
copy into mytable
  from s3://mybucket/data/files
  storage_integration = myint
  file_format = (format_name = CSV_SKIP_PIPE_HEADER);
``
```

Comment: Can you share line 2 of said file?